# Can I use other sites favicons without asking for their permission?

Tags: favicon

I am collecting RSS headlines and instead of site name I would like to use its favicon. Is that allowed by law or do I have to ask for permission from every site (in which case, it just doesn't scale)?

The example: http://i53.tinypic.com/30ws7qv.png

Implementation:

```
<a href="http://nytimes.com/article" class="nytimes-favicon">Headline</a>
```

I understand that it's not a programming question. I just couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: I would imagine that it is "fair usage" if using the icons to provide content association -- and *not* to otherwise claim endorsement or affiliation. I it were me, I would use the icon and, if sent a cease-and-desist letter (some people don't like publicity?), I would simply blacklist said icon. Happy developing. (Please keep in mind I am no lawyer and this is just a comment.)

Comment: we're programmers, not lawyers. you won't get a definitive answer here. you haven't even specified what country you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it is fine as you can add any website's RSS feed to almost any RSS reader and it will display its favicon. Just don't pass it as your own and you are golden.

Answer (score 3):

The topic was well discussed here : http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum44/768.htm

Especially, i would notice this point :

> Most webmasters will disapprove. Not
>   only are you using their image without
>   their consent, but you're using their
>   bandwidth as well.

Comment: Thanks. My case might be a little different, since I want to use favicon only attached to the link to that site (ex., <a href="http://nytimes.com/article" class="nytimes-favicon">Headline</a>) - there wordpress plugins, that do that for Wikipedia, Youtube and other links. And I would save and compress favicons on my server, without using their bandwidth. However, it seems that permission is still needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use it with asking them. Also they can sue without asking you.

Comment: I am not sure, what permissions Google has for its images search: http://www.google.com/search?hl=lt&biw=1366&bih=643&tbs=isz%3Aex%2Ciszw%3A16%2Ciszh%3A16&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=favicon

Comment: Google can afford to be sued. Having said they they make it pretty clear they aren't assuming any ownership over the images - which is something a favicon can't do. I'm just being devils advocate here, I doubt anyone will stop you but that doesn't make what you're doing safe.